# git list removed file within entire repo's historical

Tags: git

Is it possible to list all removed files within entire repo's historical in git ? 
I speak about an historical starting with an empty repo, where files were added, modified, and suppressed. I want to list all suppressed files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

This is for listing deleted file from now to the start of the repo, to keep historical order:

```
git log --reverse --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The `--diff-filter=D` argument, as shown by Arount's answer, will help you find files that were removed.  But there are a few things you might want to consider...

First, instead of using `--summary` and then piping through other tools to extract the info you want, why not just have git give you the info you want?

```
git log --name-only --diff-filter-D --format=''
```

Then you don't have to worry about your command breaking if the human-readable output format for git should happen to change (or if you move to a platform that doesn't have unix utilities on it), and if you decide you want to add info about the commit that deleted the file it's easy to do (by modifying the `--format` argument, e.g.

```
git log --name-only --diff-filter-D --format='%n---%n%s'
```

to get a text description of the commit), and fwiw it's probably a little more efficient to boot.

And of course you can still use other options like `--reverse`.

Now, as written, all answers shown so far only show files deleted in commits reachable from `HEAD`.  If you want to see the entire history of the repository - what's reachable from all branches - you need to specify that.

```
git log --name-only --diff-filter-D --format='' --all
```

And lastly, be aware that in git's mind, "rename file A as file B" is "delete file A, create file B".  By default `git log` will try to avoid including "file A" in this case under the `--diff-filter=D` output, but under some circumstances it will sneak in.  If you *do* want to see every file that disappeared (even if it re-appeared elsewhere as part of a move), include the `--no-renames` option as well.

```
git log --no-renames --diff-filter=D --format=''
```